# Adding (lots of) icons to home screen on ICS tablet

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, home-screen, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I just upgraded my Galaxy Tab 10.1 from Samsung's 3.2 variation to CyanogenMod's ICS RC1.  Most everything seems a little slicker or simpler.  However, there is one big shortcoming: it seems impossible to efficiently add multiple icons to the home screen.  From home, I have to hit the "apps" button in the top-right, find the app icon, long-press it, then drag it to the right place.  And repeat.  On the 3.2 ROM, I could just drag icons onto "mini" homescreens on the top half of the app list page.  (Is this a feature of Samsung's TouchWiz and not part of default Honeycomb?)

I've restored all my apps, so they're installed, but none are on the rather barren homescreen.  I had them somewhat organized across the 5 pages under 3.2, and I'd like to get that organization back.

Am I missing something in the CM/ICS UI that makes this easier?  Are there 3rd party apps that make this easier?  (Is the ICS homescreen the default, or specific to Cyanogenmod?)  Are the config files editable?

Comment: It's the same way on my Stock ICS Wifi Xoom.

Comment: To me it's works fine. in the application list I long press on the application in the application list ( where I launch it ) and after the screen switch to the home and I put this icon where I want.

Answer (score 2):

[Go Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nYXUuZ28ubGF1bmNoZXJleCJd)

I use this app (instead of HTC Sense) for my HTC Sensation. This works great, and there is a lot of different themes and plugins for it. Great if you're tired of the standard UI on your phone!

It also solves your problem, when you can add multiple items for your different screens. (Just tap on the ones you would like to have easy access to) :)

Answer (score 1):

[Elixir](http://bartat.hu/elixir/) lets you create a home screen widget that lets you add apps. It's easier to add apps using this widget compared to the long-press method. See the "Widgets in home screen" section of the link to see what the widget looks like.